# How to get base64 code from css rule

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got a string `'url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...GgoA)'`.

I need to invoke only base64 data from it. In output i'd like to see something like this `['iVBORw0K...GgoA']`.

Could anyone help me with creating a correct RegExp expression?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.*base64,(\w+)\)$
```

If you get group 1 from the regex, you will get the base64 data you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a regular expression like this,

```
var phrase = "url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...GgoA)"; 
var myRegexp = /base64,(.*)/;
var match = myRegexp.exec(phrase);
alert(match[1]);
```

HTH